# Which "visual" package to download?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, vpython

A `visual` package was used in [this Github repo](https://github.com/gcschmit/vpython-physics/blob/master/buoyancy/buoyancy.py). I did

```
pip search visual
```

and a long list came up in the anaconda prompt. Which one do I install? I am trying to code those programs in the url.

I have the option of installing vpython but it says this:

```
anaconda-2019.03-py37_0
jupyterlab_server-0.2.0-py37_0
liblief-0.9.0-ha925a31_2
mkl_fft-1.0.10-py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random-1.0.2-py37h343c172_0
py-lief-0.9.0-py37ha925a31_2
pywavelets-1.0.2-py37h8c2d366_0
```

Are these packages bad to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the imported `visual` refers to **Visual Python**, specifically the old [Visual Python](https://vpython.org/contents/doc.html) based on the fact that that Github repo is already old (last commit 2013). It is indicated in the [References](https://github.com/gcschmit/vpython-physics#references) section of that Github repo's README:

> VPython: http://www.vpython.org/

But that link will get you to the new Visual Python 7. That code would only probably work with the old version, so try checking out the [Documentation for Class VPython 6](https://vpython.org/contents/doc.html). Here's a sample code from the docs which uses the same import:

```
from visual import *

floor = box (pos=(0,0,0), length=4, height=0.5, width=4, color=color.blue)
ball = sphere (pos=(0,4,0), radius=1, color=color.red)
ball.velocity = vector(0,-1,0)
dt = 0.01
```

Check out the Download sections for [Windows](https://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html), [Macintosh](https://vpython.org/contents/download_mac.html), and [Linux](https://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html). For Anaconda,

> **Installing for Anaconda**
>
> If you are using the [Anaconda Python distribution](http://continuum.io/downloads), you can install
>   VPython by typing the following in a Command Prompt (*but only for
>   Python 2.7*):
>
> `conda install -c mwcraig vpython`